# Finding unique trailing characters in a string in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called `Job_Name` in a table. That column has values *AC_ACCOUNT*, *MK_SALES* and so on. I want to print the DISTINCT trailing characters after character "_" in the `Job_Name` column.

Would be able to print characters after "_" but not able to print UNIQUE characters using a single query

Tried:

```
select substr('ACCOUNT', 5, 1) from dual
union
select substr('ACCOUNT', 6, 1) from dual
union
select substr('ACCOUNT', 4, 1) from dual
```

and so on, but this will return characters which I have to concat again and keeping in mind I have to generalize this in column, this query is not feasible.

I expect the output to be *ACOUNT* for field value *AC_ACCOUNT*.

Comment: Hi Abra trying to display unique characters from ACCOUNT, i.e. output should be ACOUNT and not ACCOUNT.

Comment: So if input is _MK_SALES_ then output should be _ALE_, correct?

Comment: Should be SALE,repitition of S is suppressed.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve what you want is to write your own function. Depending on the Oracle database version you are using, the function can be written in either PL/SQL or Java or .NET

Answer (score 1):

Option which will probably perform better (than regular expressions option) if the table is large uses `SUBSTR + INSTR` combination, e.g. (thanks to @Gary for test case)

```
SQL> with tbl(job_name) as (
  2    select 'AC_ACCOUNT' from dual union all
  3    select 'MK_SALES' from dual union all
  4    select 'A_SALES' from dual union all
  5    select NULL from dual union all
  6    select 'ABC123_big_account_name' from dual
  7  )
  8  select distinct substr(job_name, instr(job_name, '_') + 1) str
  9  from tbl;

STR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT

big_account_name
SALES

SQL>
```

Comment: Note this will return a value that does not have an underscore in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `regexp_substr` with `distinct` as following:

```
Select distinct regexp_substr(job_name,'[^_]+', 1, 2) from your_table;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: You should read oracle documentation as it will be a huge description.

Answer (score 0):

This allows for any number of characters before the underscore.  What if there is no underscore? With regexp_substr() no value will be returned if there is no match.

```
with tbl(job_name) as (
  select 'AC_ACCOUNT' from dual union all
  select 'MK_SALES' from dual union all
  select 'A_SALES' from dual union all
  select NULL from dual union all
  select 'ABC123_big_account_name' from dual
)
Select distinct regexp_substr(job_name, '_(.*)', 1, 1, null, 1)
from tbl;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(JOB_NAME,'_(.*)',1,1,NULL,1)
------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT                                   

big_account_name                          
SALES                                     

4 rows selected.
```

You could use regxp_replace() If you wanted a value with no underscore returned as that returns the original string if no match is found, opposite of regexp_substr().

```
regexp_replace(job_name, '(.*?)_(.*)$', '\2')
```

Comment: Hi Gary,MANY Thanks for responding promptly. I have edited the question as there was a typo. Apologies. My intended output would be  unique characters after _.Hence I am expecting ACOUNT for AC_ACCOUNT.THANKS Again.

Comment: That's what the output is, no?  in my example, the input data set has 2 rows with SALES after the underscore, but only one instance shows in the output.

Comment: Hi Gary,no what I want is not uniqueness by rows,but uniqueness by characters in a string..Like for a value 'SALES' in a column, I should get output as SALE/ALES/in whatever order displaying unique characters.Thank You.